# Transferring SVN Properties

Tags: svn

It looks like SVN properties are stored in the local Working Copy folder, not on the server.

If this is correct, how can I duplicate these properties already defined in different files underneath the Working Copy folder to another machine?

The only property needs to be transferred is **svn:ignore**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All properties (Subversion-specific like 'svn:ignore' or user-defined) are stored in the repository. Maybe you have forgot to commit after you've set/changed them?

Answer (score 3):

`svn` properties are stored in the repository. When you change them you have to commit the change.